# Magento 2 dashboard recent order template change

Tags: magento2, blocks, reference

I have created a new module in Magento2 for order feedback, for that, I have just change the template of the recent order file.

The below mentioned file have that template`(order/recent.phtml`) with the block name of "**customer_account_dashboard_top**"

**File path:-**
`vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml`

Then I have created the `customer_account_index.xml` file on the following path
**app\code\Namespace\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\customer_account_index.xml**

and i placed the following code on that my file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_top">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Learning_Orderreview::order/recentorder.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

But still, the content came from the core(vendor folder) instead of our new view file. do you have any idea on this means kindly share with us

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Code seems quite good.I guess that you need flush the cache properly

Comment: I ran the following command for cache flush and clean
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
But still, there are no improvements